# C# Remove leading zeros from double values lower than 1

Tags: c#, .net, string, trim

For example:

```
string value = "0000.025";
```

I need 0.025

I tried

```
value.TrimStart('0');
```

but it returns **.025**

Comment: Try declaring the decimal with precision eg: decimal(4,3)

Comment: All of the answers suggesting converting to double and then going to string are erroneous. That is not a round-trip operation. Convert to decimal instead, and then back to string, if you're going to go that route.

Comment: But frankly the solution I would use is: trim the zeros as you have done. If the resulting string begins with a separator, prepend a zero. Or, if the resulting string is empty, prepend a zero.

Comment: I note that this solution does not work at all for negative numbers. Do you have to deal with them?

Comment: @EricLippert -- that's Divisadero's answer...

Comment: @EricLippert "converting to double... are errorneous" - I am interested to know this, is it because of precision?

Comment: @Ian: Because of both precision issues and representation issues. If you have more than 15 digits of precision, a double will lose them; a decimal will take up to 29 which ought to be enough. Also, doubles only represent exactly fractions that have a power of two in the denominator; 0.0025 cannot be represented as such a fraction. When you "round trip" from string to double to string, you don't necessarily get back the same digits as you put in, because sometimes the rounding to a fraction of a power of two introduces an error.

Comment: @EricLippert I get what you mean... updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you got `.025` is because `TrimStart('0')` will trim all the leading `0` until it reaches anything but `0`:

```
0000.025 //zero at start? yes! trim and continue
000.025 //zero at start? yes! trim and continue
00.025 //zero at start? yes! trim and continue
0.025 //zero at start? yes! trim and continue
.025 //zero at start? no! stop
```

One of the easiest way to solve this would be to convert the `value` to `decimal` (credit to [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)) and then to `re-print` it:

```
string value = "0000.025";
string dbrep = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("F3"); //Note, F3 here means you are printing Floating-Point with three numbers after decimal separator.
```

*(Note: as [Eric Lippert suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894101/c-sharp-remove-leading-zeros-from-double-values-lower-1/35894150?noredirect=1#comment59449427_35894101), it is better to use `decimal` than `double` if we go "a round trip" because of both precision and representation issue `double` data type may potentially have. Converting `string` which does not have a power two in the denominator to `double` and back to `string` "is not a round trip", the value would be slightly changed)*

Comment: "after comma": I think you mean "decimal separator" which will be a period (`.`) or comma (`,`) depending on current locale.

Answer (score 4):

You have to convert to `double` and then call `ToString`

```
string val = Double.Parse("0000.025").ToString();
```

Because with `double` you might have problems with the `precision` of the decimal part of the number it is better to use:

```
string val = Decimal.Parse("0000.025").ToString();
```

Comment: Better to parse to `decimal`.

Comment: Thank you. I have added this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, trim method removes all occurrences... You can add it back with

```
String.Format("0{0}", value.TrimStart('0'));
```

Comment: And what if it didn't have a leading zero, like "25.5"?

Comment: @Sinatr: The title is ambiguous. It could mean "I need to trim leading zeros from all quantites but I am having a problem with those lower than one". In which case juharr's objection is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Sinatr Yeah, if all the values are <1 and >=0 then this would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you will bring it to a simple double, it will remove the extra zeroes from the number

```
 double value = Double.Parse("0000.025");
```